Spark UDF: does not send any logs
I'm using Spark 3.3.0 on Scala 2.13.10
with the following logging dependency:
 ch.qos.logback    logback-classic   1.20.10

UDF declared as:
private val decipher: UserDefinedFunction = 
   udf { (key: String) =>
        Decoder.decode(key)
   }

And Decoder:
object Decoder {
    private val = log4s.getLogger(this.getClass)

    def decode(key: String) = {
        log.info("key")
        // other logic
   }
}

In local mode I see logs, as expected.
But on cluster no logs appear in driver and executors
I supposed, that Spark Operator (Spark run on Kubernetes) erase logback.xml file in the default directory /opt/app-root/spark/conf (during deployment).
To prevent it, my docker file create new directory for logback.xml (/opt/app-root/spark/log-conf) and copy logback.xml from jar to this direcoory.
Exploring a similar questions, I have found the recommendation to find logback-file in directory with "file://"-prefix.
So log pathconfiguration defined as:
   -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:///opt/app-root/spark/log-conf/logback.xml

But I don't see any log-data on driver and executors.
This problem concerns only UDF. Logs, produced by other part of Spark Job, saved and monitored successfully.
